# Most terminal commands either say "invalid option" or "command not found"

Tags: command-line, terminal, command

Whenever I use a command line tool, it consistently says either "invalid option" or "command not found". I'm trying to run the below command

```
. -type f -iname \*.png -delete
```

Here is the terminal response:

```
-bash: .: -t: invalid option
.: usage: . filename [arguments]
```

Don't know if this helps but when I run /bin/echo $PATH, this is what appears:

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

Can anyone help?

Thanks
A

Comment: Er, did you mean `find -type f -iname \*.png -delete` ? You don't have a command there, just arguments..

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you missed out the actual command, [`find`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find), and only had the arguments. Your command line should look like :

`find . -type f -iname \*.png -delete`

To find all files in the current directory with the `png` extension and delete them.

Comment: No problem. If it was helpful, please [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).